# how can i get coordinate values of X,Y other then plotSymbols in linechart in core-plot?

Tags: core-plot

i am new to iphone developement. can anyone tell me how can i get X,Y values of touched point in CPScatterPlot. i am able to get its plotSymbol value but not getting values of other point's XY values in line chart.thanks in advance..

Comment: are getting the ans or not shreya..

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delegate on the plot space to get the touch events. The plot space class provides methods to convert between device and data coordinates.

Comment: thanks for the reply.but delegates methods give coordinates values(CGPoints) of graph not of X and Y axis that i have set in the graph.can u give me an example to make it more clear.

Comment: hi.thanks Eric.finally i am getting X and Y axis values at touched point in plot space. but now i want to get coordinates of line that is joining two plot symbols.how can i get it? thanks.

Comment: You'll have to scan through your data and calculate that yourself. If the data is sorted, it's not hard to figure out which pair of points the touched point is between.